# Calling Stored Procedures in Hibernate with Database Independent Nature

Tags: database, hibernate

Can somebody help me in figuring out Calling Stored Procedures in Hibernate with Database Independent nature. means if i switch my database it doesn't get failed.

Suppose initially i am using Oracle and later changed to MySQL.will Dialect feature of Hibernate still work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery`. [One example here.](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/call-stored-procedures-jpa/)